# Github webhooks and pubsubhubbub permissions

Tags: github, publish-subscribe, webhooks, websub

Does anyone know what's the rational behind github ONLY allowing admins to subscribe to events in public repos?

Example: If I want to subscribe to the 'Issues' event of the nodejs/node repository, I can't because I am not an admin even though the repo is public.

What is the reason behind this decision? I can't imagine any reason for this to happen. Am I missing something here?

Also, is there any workaround this without having to scrap the issues pages that I have no admin access?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a technical question...

Comment: I'm sure it isn't :) any thought about what could be the architectural reason though?